# what do i interpret from these memory labels?

Tags: memory, computers

What do i interpret when i see this configuration for  some cache memory : `512 x 12` or for a main memory with a label `32k x 12` ?

What does these two configurations tell about the memory ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

512 words at 12 bits per word, and 32768 words at 12 bits per word.